# App Architecture

Tags: database, laravel, architecture

I am currently working on a project where i have to make a Hotel Booking Application. There will be general user who will browse through available rooms and will have to login to book. Hotel owners will have account to manage their inventory. And there will be admin section to manage the app. I am confused about what is the best approach to scale this kind of app in Laravel. Because each kind of account will require different type of authentication. I have thought multitennent approach but doesn't seem like This app falls into this category. Thanks in Advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

For this scenario, you can implement Role based authentication.

You need to create 3 roles.

1. Hotel Owner
2. Application Administrtor
3. General user.

Based on the role, you need to provide access. If you haven't developed Authentication system, you can use Entrust along with Confide.

[Entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust) provides a flexible way to add Role-based Permissions to Laravel4.

[Confide](https://github.com/Zizaco/confide) is an authentication solution for Laravel made to cut repetitive work involving the management of users.